# SQL Server fulltext index doesn't return all data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-indexing

In my table, I have a column that is `publicationDate`, publication date set as `NVarChar` that data model stored in column like these:

```
2008
2008-05
2008-10-23
```

I've created a fulltext index on this table when I get a query from SQL with this:

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKS_DETAILS WHERE CONTAINS(PublicationDate, N'2008')
```

It's just returned :

```
2008 
2008-05
```

but doesn't return `2008-10-23`

So how can I get all data that contains `2008` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just simply:

```
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM dbo.BOOKS_DETAILS 
WHERE PublicationDate LIKE N'2008%'
```

Really no need for a fulltext index....

If you search on this column `PublicationDate` rather frequently, then an index on that column would be something to look at and it might help speed up those queries.